# Help! My hermit crab molted but went missing!

Tags: lost-pet, hermit-crabs

My tiny crabbie, Pipboy, was molting for a while. This morning I found her shell and inside was a hollow shell, but no sign of the crab anywhere! Is it possible that she’s hiding? Maybe she’s buried herself? Will my other crabs try to hurt her if she’s not in her shell? Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle a disappearing hermit crab?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1575/how-to-handle-a-disappearing-hermit-crab)